# How do I set two object locations to be exactly the same?

Tags: objects

I have sculpted a character and retopologized it. I wanted to place them at the same location, so I set both their origins to the 3D cursor and moved them by 'geometry to origin', but both of them are not perfectly aligned. May I know how to make them perfectly aligned with each other without moving their position manually?

[image]

Comment: I'm new to sculpting but I think this might work: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sU5qwO9FXkAbroT2STcA5h5ebd7JJEZQ/view?usp=drive_link That's the first two ways, to just copy the position or to add drivers that copy the position. The other two ways are to use constraints: https://drive.google.com/file/d/18cGmteYaFk44qB63lRJXPHnIcXjC3BDr/view?usp=drive_link

Answer (score 0):

Set origin point to a common feature in both meshes thats easily identifiable, example - tip of the nose.
Now place both objects at same location and they should line up

Comment: Yea i think it might be the best choice if there is no way to automate it. Thank You So Much.

Comment: I'm sure you (or someone) could write a script so that you select a vertex on each mesh (like the tip of the nose as this answer says) and then click a button to align them. I wrote a tool like that for Maya years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) In Object Mode, select both meshes and right-click, then from the Object Context menu, choose Set Origin > Origin to Geometry (if you know already that your origins are centered on the mesh geometry for both objects, you can skip Step 1).

Step 2) With either mesh selected (doesn't matter which) press Shift-S and from the Snapping pie menu, choose Cursor to Selected. Now the 3D cursor has snapped to the origin of that object only.

Step 3) Select the other mesh, go back to the same Snapping menu (Shift-S) and choose Selected to Cursor.

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. But the problem is the origin point for both mesh are different even after i set origin to geometry, which makes the objects are not aligned.

Answer (score 0):

If you retopo, than the mesh should be aligned perfectly and probably only your origin is off ... so if you need to move Origin to Sculpted objet's origin - enable *Option* > **Origin**

[image]

Select your retopo object and Alt+G (in case the sculpt version is in World Origin position (0,0,0) as seen in your screen.